# Poisson parameter  and expected occurrence of an event

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, poissons-equation

In a CSV file there is data that shows only months and number of traffic accidents in each month.

In an assignment about Poisson distribution and traffic accidents, they ask:

What is the expected number of accidents per month if they are distributed with a Poisson distribution parameter μ?

They also ask: according to the data in CSV file, the average traffic accident per month is 7. How can we use this to estimate the μ?

After reading about Poisson distributions online I'm confused:

Isn't the parameter μ the same as expected number of accidents per X time?

In this case isn't μ = 7 when average traffic accident per month is also 7?

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: I think more information is needed.  Is the $\mu$ referencing one month or some other time period?

Comment: @lulu I don't know, in the assignment they just ask that question as I wrote.

Comment: Well, in that case you can guess that it refers to one month in which case $\mu$ is the expected number of accidents over the month, just as you said.